# Crash reporting and analytics: Flurry doesn't show any data despite reporting to work fine

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, flurry

Even though the logs show that the events are being logged and it sends reports, online I only see:
[image]

It can see that there are two versions, which means it's receiving some data, but it doesn't show any events or anything else.

I've waited for hours

Here is my code in native MainAcitivty.OnCreate:

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Init (() => this);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        FlurryAgent.Init (Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "mykey");
        FlurryAgent.SetVersionName ("0.1");
        LoadApplication (new App ());
        // Test:
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            FlurryAgent.LogEvent ("from android oncreate "+i);
        }
    }
```

I also test again in the PCL XamarinForms project:

```
    Flurry.Analytics.Portable.AnalyticsApi.LogEvent("From XamForms App reload");
```

All this stuff shows fine in the android log window:
[image]